# DNS on Redhat - rdnc: no server specified and no default

Tags: domain-name-system, redhat, rndc

The error as shown in the 2 pictures below:
[image: no server specified and no default]

[image: can't ping www.p0864868.com and can't get the hostname/nslookup result]

The configurations for named.conf and the zones files as shown below:
[image: named.conf]

[image: p0864868.zone file]

[image: 10-0-0.zone file]

Update 1: This is the result after applying the suggestions from "alveso".

The error has been resolved, but I still can't ping my own domain www.p0864868.com (10.0.0.1) nor can I do host or nslookup lookups as shown on previous pictures.

[image: named service]

I also attached my the changes that I made to my named.conf as well as my resolve.conf configs as shown below:
[image: named.conf that has been edited as suggested by alveso]

[image: Resolve.conf as reference in case you want to see it]

Update 2: I turned on logging by typing "rndc querylog" with the output as below when I pinged p0864868.com
[image: rndc log]

Update 3: changed permission of 10-0-0.zone and p086868.zone to 644 named:named
            Still can't ping www.p0864868.com or execute host command. It says something like Network Unreachable. 
[image: network unreachable]

Answer (score 3):

1 Find key-name and key-value. Open "/etc/rndc.key"

```
key "<key-name>" {
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret "<key-value>";
};
```

2 Configuring "/etc/rndc.conf":

```
key "<key-name>" {
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret "<key-value>";
};
options {
  default-server  localhost;
  default-key     "<key-name>";
};
```

3 Configuring "/etc/named.conf". Check control section:

```
controls {
  inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { <key-name>; };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion alvesu. Now there is no more rndc error. But I still can't ping my domain. I have attached 3 latest pictures as shown above for your reference.

Comment: See bind log(host return SERVFAIL).

Comment: Thank you.I have enabled the logging and the output is as attached above. Sounds like it is because of permission problem? may I know what is the correct permission?

Comment: depends on the file/directory, optimally named:named 644 for files.

Comment: ok I've changed the 2 zones files which are 10-0-0.zone and p0864868.zone to 644 named:named. But, still no progress.

Comment: It says something like network unreachable. I have attached a screenshots on the IP address it uses. By the way the server IP is 10.0.0.1

Comment: try restart named and attach log, after restart